# Merged DataRows are not Updated in the database but Added DataRows are. Why?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datatable, oledb

I'm currently trying to read a big bulk of excel files which are stored in a datatable called total and then i need to save this to a access database, it works as it is now but i'm afraid it will be very inefficient with the amount of excel files that needs to be read increase.

I found this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/810596/Csharp-VB-NET-Cplusplus-CLI-Create-read-and-write) and used that as a base for my writing function.

```
        private void writeAccdb()
    {
        if (File.Exists(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
            File.Delete(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        OleDbConnection conn;
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter;

        ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
        try
        {
            cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB." + verFound + ".0;Data Source=" + saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
        cat = null;
        try
        {
            conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB." + verFound + ".0;Data Source=" + saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE [Table_1] ([accdb_id] COUNTER PRIMARY KEY, [VALUE] DOUBLE, [TEXT] MEMO);", conn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { if (ex != null) ex = null;
        }

        adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Table_1]", conn);
        OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
        DataTable dtMain = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dtMain);



        //Slow process
        foreach (DataRow row in total.Rows)
        {
            dtMain.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
        }
        //Slow process



        adapter.Update(dtMain);
        conn.Close();
    }
```

I have tried using .Merge() and importrow but i always end up with a 180kb file only containing the column names and what type they hold but when i inspect dtmain it does hold the variables that i got from total, but when i itemarray it works properly.

While I'm already asking about this matter, when a file is created, it says that the program is still using it until i close the program, but as far as i can see everything is closed that interacts with the file, i tried using dispose on all variables but it still remains, what could be the issue here?

**edit**

So my main question is why dtMain when merged with total doesn't work, but when each line is individually added it does?

**edit 2**

The user chooses a directory from which they want to import all excel files

total is set as a new datatable and all columns are populated.

Iteration over all excel files that were found in the directory are read using

```
        private OleDbConnection getExcelFile(string file)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn;
        if (verFound != "")
            return new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB." + verFound + ".0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties='Excel " + verFound + ".0 XML;HDR=YES;';");
        foreach(string v in versions){
            try{
                conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB." + v + ".0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties='Excel " + v + ".0 XML;HDR=YES;';");
                conn.Open();
                conn.Close();
                verFound = v;
                return conn;
            } catch {
                log("Version " + v + " är ej korrekt.");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Then i try to merge the excel files data with total, but if the structure is incorrect it's ignored.

Once all files have been merged a datagridview gets total as datasource.

Now the user will have the option to remove rows depending on specific criterias.

And at last the save process, so in whole it's just a straight import with a option to exclude rows.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The best way to get great answers is to try to ask just one very specific question at a time. I'm not sure what the actual question is here. It has to be more than just a general request for help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify: (1) Are you combining the contents of several Excel files into the `total` DataTable before trying to insert the data into Access? (2) Are you modifying the Excel data or populating additional columns in `total`, or is it just a straight import from Excel?

Comment: Are you using an OleDbDataAdapter to `.fill` a DataTable with the data from each Excel file and then using `.Merge` to push that data into the `total` DataTable?

Comment: That's exactly right.
`OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
                        DataTable data = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(data);
                        try
                        {
                            total.Merge(data);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            corruptFiles = corruptFiles + file + "\r\n";
                            log(file + " verkar inte följa normen, ignoreras.");
                        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my main question is why dtMain when merged with total doesn't work, but when each line is individually added it does?

The reason is because

1. when an existing DataRow is copied or merged into another DataTable the `RowState` of the DataRow stays the same, and
2. when we use the `.fill` method of an OleDbDataAdapter to populate a DataTable all of the rows are created with a RowState of "Unchanged"

So, when you fill your upstream DataTables from Excel the rows are inserted as "Unchanged", and when those rows ultimately get merged into the "total" DataTable they are still "Unchanged".

Example code:

```cs
string excelFileSpec = @"C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\Book1.xlsx";
string excelConnStr =
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        "Data Source=" + excelFileSpec + ";" +
        "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";";
using (var excelCon = new OleDbConnection(excelConnStr))
{
    using (var excelDA = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", excelCon))
    {
        var total = new DataTable();
        excelDA.Fill(total);
        Console.WriteLine("DataAdapter.fill() put {0} row(s) into \"total\":", total.Rows.Count);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow r in total.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    total row[{0}]: RowState is \"{1}\"", i++, r.RowState);
        }
        DataTable dtMain = total.Clone();
        dtMain.Merge(total);
        Console.WriteLine("dtMain.Merge(total); completed. \"dtMain\" contains {0} row(s):", dtMain.Rows.Count);
        i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow r in dtMain.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    dtMain row[{0}]: RowState is \"{1}\"", i++, r.RowState);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
DataAdapter.fill() put 1 row(s) into "total":
    total row[0]: RowState is "Unchanged"
dtMain.Merge(total); completed. "dtMain" contains 1 row(s):
    dtMain row[0]: RowState is "Unchanged"
```

Therefore, when your other DataAdapter goes to `.Update` the Access database it sees that all of the rows in "dtMain" are "Unchanged" and it is under the impression that there is nothing to do.

On the other hand, when you `.Add` each row to "dtMain" they are inserted into the DataTable as "Added" so when the `.Update` happens it actually does send the "Added" rows to the Access database.

Comment: Ah you're right, kinda weird that they're never set to added since they're actually added.
Thank you very much!